# 68000, portable JIT library

Tags: c, code-generation, jit, 68000

There are several JIT libraries, but is there any which emits Motorola 68000 style instructions, such as for instance 68000, 68040, 68060 or any of the Coldfire CPUs?

Bonus points if it could emit for other platforms too, but 68k is most important.

Something easily integrated with C is preferred, but other languages are interesting too.

Ideally something like [libjit](http://www.gnu.org/software/dotgnu/libjit-doc/libjit_1.html#SEC1), but with a 68k backend.

Comment: @Jonas Elfström, for a genetic algorithm.

Comment: In what programming language?

Comment: @Jonas Elfström, I am not sure. Maybe something custom.

Comment: "Or higher" includes the ColdFire lineage or only 680x0?

Comment: @Potatoswatter, ColdFire is OK too.

Comment: Well, the bee's knees with JITs is LLVM... which doesn't support the 68k. And the alternative is GNU Lightning... which doesn't support the 68k. I'm afraid you might be kinda stuffed. Depending how badly you need it, you may want to consider paying the LLVM people for a 68k port, but of course that will take time (and money).

Comment: @David Given, there is a guy in the LLVM camp interested in creating an m68k target.  But LLVM is kind of big, also I heard the JIT in LLVM is _not_ the bees' knee, merely adequate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this doesn't really answer your question, you could consider generating the 68k machine code yourself.  It shouldn't be too terribly difficult if you are already familiar with 68k assembly.

The [Motorola M68000 Family Programmer's Reference Manual](http://www.freescale.com/files/archives/doc/ref_manual/M68000PRM.pdf) documents the syntax, availability, and bit configuration of every 680x0 instruction.  However, a less tedious way to figure out the machine code for instructions is to use a 68k assembler that can generate a listing of the hex codes for each instruction produced.  If you're on Windows, [Easy68K](http://www.easy68k.com/) should be able to generate such a listing, but I haven't tried it myself.

If you're not on Windows, you could try [this assembler](http://www.cse.iitm.ac.in/~jvimal/assign/68000/m68k-asm-sim.tar.bz2) (only supports 68000, I think).  You'll have to blow the dust off of it, but it works (at least in Linux).  The command-line assembler (`assembler/asm`) has a `-l` flag that tells the assembler to generate a listing.  Example:

```
$ asmlab/assembler/asm -ln test.asm
68000 Assembler by PGM

No errors detected
No warnings generated
```

**test.asm**

*Leading space is required before each instruction, and the assembler doesn't handle whitespace between tokens well.*

```
 move.l #$12345678,-(a6)
 jmp ($12345678)
 rts
```

**test.LIS**

```
00000000  2D3C 12345678                      1   move.l #$12345678,-(a6)
00000006  4EF9 12345678                      2   jmp ($12345678)
0000000C  4E75                               3   rts

No errors detected
No warnings generated
```

Comment: I also found VASM and VBCC very promising.

Comment: I'm currently playing around with generating 68000 code and have found easy68k to be excellent for testing the generated code and it shows the machine code by the side of each line.